# How to know if two matrices have the same size [Java]

Tags: java, recursion

I'm a new programmer that just started learning recursive programming. I'm trying to compare to matrices' sizes recursively.

```
public static boolean mismasFilas(int[][] m1, int[][] m2, int fila) {
    boolean sol = true;
    int k = 0, h = 0;
    if (fila >= 0) {
        if (m1[fila].length != m2[fila].length) {
            
            return false;
        } else {
            mismasFilas(m1, m2, fila - 1);
        }
    }
    return sol;
}
```

It's working so far good but that `return false;` statement is not working as intended, it's not exiting the method. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: With "same size" do you mean "same dimensions"? Why use recursion at all if you're dealing with only 2 levels? A simple loop for the 2nd level would suffice: `if(m1.length!=m2.length) {return false;} for(int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) { if(m1[i].length != m2[i].length) { return false; }} return true;`

Comment: Note that in the `else` block, you are doing a recursive call but you ignore the return value of the `mismasFilas` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the 2-dimensional `arrays` are rectangular matrices and that both have the same dimensions, you can do:

```
public static boolean isRectangle2DArray(int[][] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).mapToInt(row -> row.length).distinct().count() == 1;
}

public static boolean sameDimensions(int[][] m1, int[][] m2) {
    return isRectangle2DArray(m1) && isRectangle2DArray(m2) 
            && m1.length == m2.length && m1[0].length == m2[0].length;
}
```

If you don't want to check if the 2-dimensional `arrays` are rectangular you can do:

```
public static boolean sameDimensions(int[][] m1, int[][] m2) {
    if (m1.length != m2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
        if (m1[i].length != m2[i].length) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you can use `stream` you can also do:

```
public static boolean sameDimensions(int[][] m1, int[][] m2) {
    return m1.length == m2.length && 
            IntStream.range(0, m1.length)
                    .allMatch(i -> m1[i].length == m2[i].length);
}
```

Then:

```
int[][] m1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

int[][] m2 = {{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};

int[][] m3 = {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}};

System.out.println("(m1, m2): " + sameDimensions(m1, m2));
    
System.out.println("(m1, m3): " + sameDimensions(m1, m3));
```

Output:

```
(m1, m2): true
(m1, m3): false
```